# to converting upper and lower case why we add +32 and -32 pleas explain

Tags: c

Here is a code snippet and I didn't get why +32 and -32 is getting add or subtract to make characters upper case lower case.

```
/******** function definition *******/
void stringLwr(char *s)
{
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z'){
            s[i]=s[i]+32;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

void stringUpr(char *s)
{
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z'){
            s[i]=s[i]-32;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

for more reference, I was learning it on a website **[C program to convert in Upper and Lower case.](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/c-program-to-convert-string-into-lower-and-upper-case.aspx)**

Comment: Strange. Usually it is done with bit-flipping to make it even harder for beginners to understand - `s[i]=s[i] ^ 32`.

Comment: It's all about character set encodings. People will tell you about ASCII but you should really find out which encoding you want to support in your program _and document it_ —probably it should match your terminal. In Linux run `locale`; in WIndows run `chcp` to find out which [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Character_sets) you are using. Standard C libraries are designed to work with many such encodings so you would use them once you learn what they do.

Comment: `32` is an example of poor programming practice: _A magic number._ The fact that you have to ask proves that the program could be clearer, as @RSahu's answer shows.

Answer (score 6):

The ASCII codes for `a`-`z` are 97-122.
The ASCII codes for `A`-`Z` are 65-90.

To get `A` from `a`, you need to subtract 32.
To get `a` from `A`, you need to add 32.

To make the code a little more clear, you can use:

```
        s[i] += ('a' - 'A');
        // 'a' = 'A' + ('a' - 'A');
```

when converting an uppercase letter to a lowercase letter and

```
        s[i] += ('A' - 'a');
        // 'A' = 'a' + ('A' - 'a');
```

when converting a lowercase letter to an uppercase letter.

Comment: guess you meant *subtract* in the line "To get A from a, you need to add 32 to a."

Answer (score 1):

All the mystery is in the ASCII code..
Code of `A = 65 a=97`
SO now changing just means adding or subtracting 32. That's it.

```
            Difference
A=65  a=97  32
B=66  b=98  32
C=67  c=99  32
D=68  d=100 32
...   ...
..    ..
```

By the way this is part of any basic C/C++ book.

Now in case you want to change from 'a' to 'A' you have to subtract 32 becuase that's what the ascii code for 'A' corresponds.

Similar is the logic for 'A' to 'a' (add 32).

Another thing is that 'a' gives us the numeric ascii value.

```
printf("%c", 66); ===> b
printf("%d", 'c');===> 67
```

Answer (score 0):

the ascii value of A is 65 and a is 97 
therefore, 
65 + 32 = 97 take you to lower case.
97 - 32 = 65 take you to upper case.

you can look up 
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, it's because the ASCII representation of each lower case letter happens to be 32 greater than the representation of the corresponding lower case letter.

It's rarely a good idea to depend on this. There are character sets other than ASCII; in EBCDIC, for example, this will not work.

The standard functions `toupper` and `tolower`, declared in `<ctype.h>`, will *portably* convert characters to upper or lower case (and will map non-letters to themselves). Rather than

```
if(s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z'){
    s[i]=s[i]+32;
}
```

you can write:

```
s[i] = toupper((unsigned char)s[i]);
```

(The cast to `unsigned char` is needed because of an unfortunate glitch in the way these functions are defined.)

Answer (score 0):

Why does one not use the functions for that from ctype.h?